# C# - I/O na rede

Tags: c#, redes, path, io

Eu tenho um programa que faz I/O de arquivos (criar, editar,salvar), mas preciso colocar ele para fazer esse I/O com arquivos que estão na rede da empresa, tanto leitura quanto escrita.

Minha dúvida é: O meu programa precisa de permissão de leitura e escrita de arquivos, ou o usuário do programa que precisa dessas permissões na maquina dele para com a rede?

Se for o usuário que precisa ter essa permissão, eu posso colocar o endereço do servidor da rede no `Path` que uso para salvar os arquivos do programa? Ou é necessário algo mais?

Se for permissão do meu programa, escrito em C#, é necessário o que exatamente?

Comment: Você já chegou a testar pra ver o que acontece?

Comment: Ainda não amigo @Laerte, ainda não tenho acesso a rede, queria confirmar isso antes de solicitar o acesso.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> O meu programa precisa de permissão de leitura e escrita de arquivos, ou o usuário do programa que precisa dessas permissões na maquina dele para com a rede?

Quem precisa ter a permissão de leitura/escrita é o usuário e não o aplicativo.

> Se for o usuário que precisa ter essa permissão, eu posso colocar o endereço do servidor da rede no Path que uso para salvar os arquivos do programa? ou é necessário algo mais?

Sim, você deve usar o caminho da rede como se fosse um caminho local. É tudo igual.

---

É claro que podem haver algumas restrições que invalidem o que foi dito acima, mas como não há maiores detalhes, não há como ter certeza.

Comment: Obrigado, vou solicitar o ip da rede e testar.

Answer (score 2):

Vamos lá, seu programa sobre rodar sob a autenticação de um usuário, sempre. Com isso em mente fica fácil entender que esse usuário deve sim ter acesso ao arquivo que deseja abrir via app.

Porém, nem sempre o mesmo usuário que roda sua app é o mesmo que irá acessar o arquivo remotamente. Você pode sim ter uma conta de acesso exclusivo para arquivo remotos.

Para esse caso, você pode usar a técnica de **impersonate**. Encontrei esse arquivo em pt-br [Trabalhando com Impersonate e Web](http://imasters.com.br/artigo/16406/dotnet/trabalhando-com-impersonate-e-web/?trace=1519021197&source=single). No final vc fará algo assim:

```
using (ImpersonateConnection)
{
    // Este trecho de código irá rodar sob outro usuário
    var file = File.OpenRead(@"\\Servidor\PastaCompartilhada\arquivo.txt");
    // ... outra coisas
}
```

Comment: legal Thiago, vou estudar a respeito e decidir com a equipe qual a melhor abordagem, obrigado pela ajuda.