# Como posso trabalhar com ficheiros em directorias de rede em .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, redes, io

Como posso aceder a ficheiros presentes em directorias de rede em .Net?
Aceder a ficheiros locais é simples, posso fazer `Directory.EnumerateFiles("C:\\", "*.*")`.

Mas `Directory.EnumerateFiles("\\\\10.88.0.1\\rec", "*.*")` nao é válido.

Como posso aceder a ficheiros de outras redes?

Comment: Possivel duplicada de https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/126403/c-i-o-na-rede?rq=1

Comment: Possivel duplicada de https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/130381/como-copiar-um-arquivo-da-rede-para-o-meu-computador-usando-c?rq=1

Comment: muito provavel vc n estar fazendo uso de credenciais de uma  olhada  nesse artigo https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-access-network-drive-using-c-sharp